# Error conversion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, error-analysis

$\alpha_L = \frac{1}{a}\frac{da}{dT}$

I know error in $a$, i.e., $da$

I need to find out $d\alpha$ from data of $da$.

$d\alpha_L = -\frac{1}{a^2}\frac{da}{dT}da$

Is this correct?

Note:

$\alpha_L$ =  Linear thermal expansivity

$a$ = Lattice constant

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/93514/

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing yourself with two different uses of $da$, it would be better to make the error $\delta a$  Then if you consider $\frac {da}{dT}$ to be a constant you will be correct.